# Does typescript HTML Content is not recorded in JMeter

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Using Angular 9 Application written using Typescript, there the HTML Content is not visible, and due to this not able to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JMeter is backend-agnostic, it doesn't  care what is the underlying technology used in the system under test.
2. Properly configured [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) is capable of recording [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and/or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) requests which should be sufficient for testing your application because browsers mainly send HTTP requests and render the responses

If your application looks/behaves differently when you're accessing it using JMeter as a proxy the reasons might be in:

1. You didn't import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser (or the certificate has expired), see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more details, double check your configuration when it comes to proxy and certificate settings
2. You accessed the application previously and it is partly or fully blocked by [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), in this case clear your browsing history at least for the domain you're testing

Also be aware of alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium). In this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and due to "non-invasive" nature of the extension you shouldn't experience any problems with browsing experience.

Comment: No the requests are being recorded properly, but when viewing it in HTML downloaded resource form, in the response body it is not visible, and